# Sort time periods with "IF" in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a database in power BI with a time column only the first two digits of the hour, and I need to separate these times into periods. It would be to make an "IF" with two conditions, I structured it more or less like this

```
> IF hour >= 6 < 12, "morning period", 
> IF hour >= 12 < 18, "Afternoon period", 
> IF hour >= 18 <= 23, "Night period", 
> IF hour >= 0 < 6, "Early morning period"
```

In DAX I put exactly like this

**

```
Periods = IF(
     'cmu_viagens_dw cmu_vgm'[time] >= 6,
     "Morning Period",
         IF('cmu_viagens_dw cmu_vgm'[hour] < 12,
         "Morning Period",
             IF('cmu_viagens_dw cmu_vgm'[time] >= 12,
             "Afternoon Period",
                 IF('cmu_viagens_dw cmu_vgm'[hour] < 18,
                 "Afternoon Period" ))))
```

**

But it is only considering the "Morning Period" for all fields, it is not following the other periods that I need. How can I structure this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your logic like this: Please create a calculated column and paste this code: You can obtain a similar result by using switch() function in dax.

```
PartOfDay = 
IF(AND('YourTable'[Hour] >=0,'YourTable'[Hour]< 6),"Early morning period",
IF(AND('YourTable'[Hour] >=6,'YourTable'[Hour]< 12),"morning period",
IF(AND('YourTable'[Hour] >=12,'YourTable'[Hour]< 18),"Afternoon period",
"Night period")))
```

You can do it also with SWITCH() function in DAX:

```
PartOfDay_SWITCH = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
AND('TimeSlicer'[Hour] >=0,'TimeSlicer'[Hour]< 6),"Early morning period",
AND('TimeSlicer'[Hour] >=6,'TimeSlicer'[Hour]< 12),"morning period",
AND('TimeSlicer'[Hour] >=12,'TimeSlicer'[Hour]< 18),"Afternoon period",
"Night period")
```